# Flutter Dart Error with padding and TextAlign

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, padding

I'm trying to remove the space between each Card and get the Meal Text in the Center

It comes from the *EdgeInsets.only(top:220),* but this is needed due to the Space between the AppBar .

Tried to Create a new Widget but this doesn't work then i get a StreamBuilder Error. I also tried to add to the margin *MediaQuery.removePadding(removeTop: true),* but there i get an error aswell.

My Secound Problem i want that the Meal Text is in the middle, i added the textAlign: TextAlign.center. At the Date it is working but why isn't it at the top one?

**Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/models/Widgets/whenAndWhatToEat.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/models/global.dart';


class MealTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final MealsAndWhen mealsAndWhen;
  MealTile ({ this.mealsAndWhen });
  
  @override
  MealTileState createState() {
    return MealTileState();
  }
}
class MealTileState extends State<MealTile> {
  String id;
  final db = Firestore.instance;
  String meal;

  Widget buildItem(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 220),
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Meal: ${doc.data['Meal']}',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            Text(
              'Date: ${doc.data['Date']}',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 12),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(width: 8),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () => deleteData(doc),
                  child: Text('Delete',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: lightBlueColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: darkGreyColor,
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: db.collection('mealList').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column(children: snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) => buildItem(doc)).toList());
              } else {
                return SizedBox();
              }
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void deleteData(DocumentSnapshot doc) async {
    await db.collection('mealList').document(doc.documentID).delete();
    setState(() => id = null);
  }
}
```

[[image: Space between Card]]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying the padding to the card, wrap your `ListView` inside a `Padding` widget and apply it there.

To align the `Text`, wrap it in a `Center` widget.

Answer (score 0):

To add padding to `Text` Widgets, just add `padding` property to `Container`

eg:

```
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
```

To Center your `Text` just replace `CrossAxisAlignment.start` with `CrossAxisAlignment.center`

```
Column(
    **crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,**
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        'Meal: Example Meal',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 24,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.white),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      Text(
        'Date: Example Date',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.white),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Here's the output:
[image: Flutter Output]